# Why does ruby require parentheses here?

Tags: ruby, mri

When I try to do

```
assert_equal { dry: true }, res
```

I get

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

        assert_equal { dry: true }, res
```

but

```
assert_equal({ dry: true }, res)
```

works fine. Why is first form not sufficient for ruby to understand what
I mean? Or to be more precise, what does Ruby think I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the curly braces are interpreted as delimiting a block. Since `dry: true` is not a legal expression, you get a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: good to know, thank you :)